# SwiftUI pass Binding by ref to a child ViewModel

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, I am trying to create some binding between a parent ViewModel and a child ViewModel, here is a simplified example of my scenario:

The parent component:

```swift
class ParentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "John Doe"

    func updateName() {
        self.name = "Jonnie Deer"
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ParentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.name)
            ChildView(name: $viewModel.name)
            // tapping the button the text on parent view is updated but not in child view
            Button("Update", action: viewModel.updateName)
        }
    }
}
```

The child component:

```swift
class ChildViewModel : ObservableObject {
    var name: Binding<String>
    
    var displayName: String {
        get {
            return "Hello " + name.wrappedValue
        }
    }
    
    init(name: Binding<String>) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ChildViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.displayName)
    }
    
    init(name: Binding<String>) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ChildViewModel(name: name))
    }
}
```

So, as stated in the comments, when I tap the button on the parent component the name is not getting updated in ChildView, as if the binding is lost...
Is there any other way to update view model with the updated value? say something like `getDerivedStateFromProps` in React (becuase when tapping the button the `ChildView::init` method is called with the new name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apple is very big on the concept of a Single Source of Truth(SSoT), and keeping it in mind will keep you from getting into the weeds in code like this. The problem you are having is that while you are using a `Binding` to instantiate the child view, you are turning around and using it as a `@StateObject`. When you do that, you are breaking the connection as `@StateObject` is supposed to sit at the top of the SSoT hierarchy. It designates your SSoT. Otherwise, you have two SSoTs, so you can only update one. The view model in `ChildView` should be an `@ObservedObject` so that it connects back up the hierarchy. Also, you can directly instantiate the `ChildViewModel` when you call `ChildView`. The initializer just serves to decouple things. Your views would look like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ParentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.name)
            // You can directly use the ChildViewModel to instantiate the ChildView
            ChildView(viewModel: ChildViewModel(name: $viewModel.name))
            Button("Update", action: viewModel.updateName)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    // Make this an @ObservedObject not a @StateObject
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChildViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.displayName)
    }
}
```

Neither view model is changed.

Comment: As I said in my question I posted a minimal and super simplified example, in reality the ChildViewModel IS the state object of the ChildView, it holds more state props of the ChildView, and if I understand correctly from your answer the ChildViewModel will get re-created on every parent state change and the ChildView will lose all state saved in ChildViewModel.
Also I rather keep ChildViewModel private to the Child component...
I just need a way to update ChildViewModel props when ChildView updates, like didUpdateWidget on Flutter

Comment: SwiftUI is not React, Flutter, or JetPack Compose. It really won't do this like they do. The only thing you could possibly do, and you will hate it with a passion, is subscribe to the `ChildViewModel` from the `ParentViewModel`. However, you will have multiple `ChildViewModels` as they are being instantiated based on data from the, and you will be tightly coupling your view models. And frankly, I am not sure it would work as you will have to deal with the strong references between the two models.

Comment: Yes, I guess it will get there eventually... I wonder if Apple uses SwiftUI in its own applications...

Comment: Not all, but they are adding to them every year. However, this is a fundamental paradigm of SwiftUI. I don't see them changing this.

Comment: You saved my evening! --> // Make this an \@ObservedObject not a \@StateObject

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI View structs are a View model already so you can just remove those view model objects and do `@State var name = “John”` in ParentView and `@Binding var name: String` in `ChildView`. Then pass `$name` into `ChildView`’s `init` which gives you write access as if `ParentView` was a view model object (`let` if you only need read access).

By using `@State` and `@Binding` you get the reference type semantics you want inside a value type which is the power of SwiftUI. If you just use objects you lose that benefit and have more work to do.

We usually only use `ObservableObject` for loading/saving models but we can also use it for async loaders/fetchers where we want to tie some controller behaviour to the view on screen lifecycle (thats why it would be called async) but for data transient to a view we always use `@State` and `@Binding`. You can extract related vars into their own struct and use mutating funcs for other logic and thus have a single `@State` struct used by `body` instead of multiple. This way it can still be testable like a view model object in UIKit would be.

Logic, i.e. funcs, can be declared anywhere in Swift, it is not efficient to make a class just for logic. Just change the func from something that updates a class's property to one that returns something.

Comment: But I need the ViewModels as that's where I want to manage any ui/business logic, I want my Views to just do the render stuff.

Comment: The thing you need to know is the View structs in SwiftUI are just data structs they don't render anything. SwiftUI takes the View structs and diffs them and uses that to render things on screen for you automatically.

Comment: Yeah, by "render stuff" I meant that I rather my views just define the view structure and all logic like what to display, event handlers etc be handled by the view models. So in the simplified example above, the ChildView gets some "name" from the parent, but the ChildViewModel, based on some logic, decides what should be displayed. I know that maybe that's not a "classic" viewmodel, but many frameworks (like React, Flutter, JetPack Compose) let me achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to hold the `name` in a state variable in the ChildView. So something like this:

```
class ChildViewModel : ObservableObject {
    // only handle the logic here and pass the name as a parameter each time :( 
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ChildViewModel()

    @Binding var displayName: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(displayName)
    }
}
```

I'm not really happy with this solution, but it's the only way I found so far to keep the viewModels separate and not recreating the ChildViewModel with each redraw.